# count of check boxes and unbale to get label of check box

Tags: reactjs

i have a list of checkboxes...i just need to count of checked checkboxes...if i checked count should be increase , if i unchecked count should be decrease....i am not getting label name also.....can any on help on these..please..

this is the link of code sand box: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-margulis-wwbip?file=/src/App.js:265-318

CheckboxComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import FormGroup from "@material-ui/core/FormGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import { List, ListItem } from "@material-ui/core";

class CheckboxComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const arr = ["Checkbox1", "Checkbox2", "Checkbox3"];
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <FormGroup aria-label="position" row>
          <List className="courses-college-regis">
            <ListItem button>
              {arr.map(a => (
                <FormControlLabel
                  name={a}
                  type="checkbox"
                  control={<Checkbox color="primary" />}
                />
              ))}
            </ListItem>
          </List>
        </FormGroup>
        count:
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default CheckboxComponent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to first handle the onChange event on the checkbox to determine when a box is checked or unchecked.  You can use hooks for this to store the checked boxes into an array, but first you'll need to convert the class into a function.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import FormGroup from "@material-ui/core/FormGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import { List, ListItem } from "@material-ui/core";


const CheckboxComponent = () => {
  const arr = ["Checkbox1", "Checkbox2", "Checkbox3"];
  const [ checkedBoxes, setCheckedBoxes ]= React.useState([])
  const onChange = (name, e) => {
    const isChecked = e.target.checked
    if (isChecked) {
      setCheckedBoxes(checkedBoxes.concat(name))
    } else {
      setCheckedBoxes(checkedBoxes.filter(x => x !== name))
    }
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <FormGroup aria-label="position" row>
        <List className="courses-college-regis">
          <ListItem button>
            {arr.map(a => (
              <FormControlLabel
                key={a}
                name={a}
                type="checkbox"
                control={<Checkbox color="primary" onChange={onChange.bind(undefined, a)} />}
              />
            ))}
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      </FormGroup>
      count: {checkedBoxes.length}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default CheckboxComponent;
```

Comment: thanks very much rob...i unable to get label also...can you help on that please

Comment: What do you mean by label?  I assumed label was the values in arr (i.e. Checkbox1).  Did you want to have FormControlLabel instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import FormGroup from "@material-ui/core/FormGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import { List, ListItem } from "@material-ui/core";

// const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(true);
class CheckboxComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
      checked: true
    };
  }
  ChangeCheckBox = e => {
    let checked = e.target.checked;
    let { count } = this.state;
    if (checked) {
      console.log("checked");
      count++;
    } else {
      console.log("un-checked");
      count--;
    }
    this.setState({ count });
    console.log(count);
  };
  render() {
    const arr = ["Checkbox1", "Checkbox2", "Checkbox3"];
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <FormGroup aria-label="position" row>
          <List className="courses-college-regis">
            {arr.map(a => (
              <ListItem button>
                <FormControlLabel
                  label={a}
                  type="checkbox"
                  control={
                    <Checkbox color="primary" onChange={this.ChangeCheckBox} />
                  }
                />
              </ListItem>
            ))}
          </List>
        </FormGroup>
        count:{this.state.count}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default CheckboxComponent;
```